# Taking too long to retrieve and display the result in the telerik grid.

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-2, dynamic, join, telerik-grid

I have a MVC application in which I need to display the data from 3 tables. I am using entity model for it. Out of these, in 2 I have made the association:users and payment table.

And 3rd table `month_<monthid>` is created every month to store the users to whom the magazine is sent. The table name `month_<monthid>` is generated dynamically by selecting the month so in order to fetch the data I have used ExeuteStoreQuery. For small amount of data the listing is fast but for large amount it is very slow.

Now I have created a class to bind to grid which will include all the fields from the 3 tables to display.
But here when I am getting the large volume of data about 12000 then it is taking about 30 min to go through the loop and assigning the data to the class object and then adding to the list of the result which is finally binded to telerik grid.

I am hereby attaching the sample code using a link. Is there any direct way to bind the query result of joined tables to grid instead of going through the loop and preparing the list for the model class I think that will save time.
The code block of preparing the list using the Executestorequery is under the function GetuserList().

```
foreach (var r in result)
                {

                    Result  objresult = new Result();
                    var paymentresult = from sub in dtpayment.AsEnumerable() where sub.Field<int>("user_id") == r.user_id select sub;
                    if (paymentresult.Count() > 0)
                    {

                        objresult.amount_paid = paymentresult.FirstOrDefault().Field<decimal>("amount_paid");
                        objresult.magzine_id = paymentresult.FirstOrDefault().Field<int>("magzine_id");
                    }
                    objresult.address=r.address;
                    objresult.email=r.email;
                    objresult.name=r.name;
                    objresult.user_id=r.user_id;
                    objresult.month= smonth;
                    lstresult.Add(objresult);
                }
```

This code block of for loop is taking very time where I am using ExceuteStoreQuery.
But I have observed that simply by joining the users and payment table using LINQ query to get all the 12000 records i.e no involvement of month table the result is appearing faster.
So,can you suggest any way to improve the performance of my application?

Also include the database structure with the sample code.
Below is the link to sample

http://sampletestone.s3.amazonaws.com/magzine.7z?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAINHDRCMKC5GUSNFA&Expires=1303583399&Signature=8o8Wn6UNjbEl3dIyipAX9xH29Hg%3D

supriya

Answer (score 0):

Nobody in the world wants to see 12,000 records.  You should look at implementing paging & searching functionality.